# connect spring boot with mongodb using java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this structure

```
project  (module.pom)
- connection                     (module.jar)
      - src/main/java
            -com.mycompany.connection
                -connectionBD.class
      - ...
      - pom.xml
- person                         (module.jar)
      - src/main/java
            - com.mycompany.person
                -personApplication.class
            - com.mycompany.person.controller
                -...
            - com.mycompany.person.model
                -...
      - src/main/resources
      - ...
      - pom.xml
pom.xml
```

my **connectionBD.class** class is this.

```
@Configuration
public class connectionBD {

    @Bean
    public MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory(){
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory("mongo://localhost:27017/lydsam");
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDatabaseFactory());
    }
}
```

and my **PersonApplication.class** class that is in another module.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.mycompany.person", "com.mycompany.connection" })
public class PersonApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(PersonApplication.class, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

### When I run the project, I get an error saying that my connection to my database is wrong and I don't know what the problem is.
Somebody could help me.

Error message

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/connection/connectionBD.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/connection/connectionBD.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://
```

Comment: Could you please share the log?

Comment: Remove your `connectionDB` class/configuration and let Spring Boot do it. Just add the `spring.data.mongodb.uri=<your-config-url>` and Spring Boot will set things up for you. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://

You need to edit. `mongo` -> `mongodb` [SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.html)

```
@Configuration
public class connectionBD {

    @Bean
    public MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory(){
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory("mongodb://localhost:27017/lydsam");
    }
}
```

Comment: OR SimpleMongoClientDbFactory if you are using older version